# Can a revolver with ice bullets work?

Tags: magic, steampunk

In a steampunk fantasy world one of my characters has ice magic and he uses a revolver as a weapon so that when he runs out of bullets he can create them using his magic.

I was wondering whether this would work or I should rethink the idea.

Comment: Welcome to WorldBuilding *Hotllum*! We already have quite a few interesting questions on the site and I think the one I linked already answers your question. If it doesn't please [edit] your question to show in which ways the answers to the other question aren't helping you. If you have a moment please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site. Have fun!

Comment: He can't create gunpowder, so no.

Comment: @Bert Haddad Ice has a lower density than metal so it doesn't need as much force to propel it. A pneumatic gun might work. Secondly, the heat has to go somewhere after making ice. Channeling it into air behind the bullet might be sufficient.